# XStream canConvert issue for paramterised generics

Tags: generics, serialization, xstream

I have a requirement where i have to write a custom XStream MapConverter that just converts a specific type of map. To give an example, i would want my custom converter to just work with Map(String, Date) maps. I need to achieve this by overriding the canConvert method.  As of now, this is the canConvert method that i have written :

```
@Override  
public boolean canConvert(Class clazz) {  
    return (!clazz.equals(Object.class) && Map.class.isAssignableFrom(clazz));  
}
```

But this would work for all the type of maps. Since "java.lang.Class" does not expose any method that gives information about the type of parameters, for generic collections, i am unable to achieve the desired result in my canConvert method.

One workaround i could think is of creating a dummy wrapper class around Map(String, Date) and using that to implement the canConvert method. Could someone suggest a better way of tackling this issue in canConvert method ?

Answer (score 0):

You can't do much with generics here since they're not present at runtime. You could try grabbing the first key and entry value and checking their types. This obviously wouldn't work for an empty map, but if a map is empty you probably don't need to convert it anyways.

```
Map<String, Date> m = new HashMap<String, Date>();
m.put("test", new Date());
Object key = m.keySet().iterator().next();
Object value = m.get(key);

System.out.println(key.getClass().isAssignableFrom(String.class));
System.out.println(value.getClass().isAssignableFrom(Date.class));
```

Other than that it's like you say, you pretty much have to make your own wrapper class or roll a custom implementation of Map that only accepts String keys and Date values.

Comment: This is trivially extended to support empty maps, but you might run into issues with heterogeneous maps (i.e. the code assumes that all values in the map are of the same type, which might not be true).

Comment: I don't think the code mentioned here would work because the only parameter available in the canConvert() method is the class name . When this method is called by XStream framework, there is no access to the data, but only to the class type.